# multiple views in a rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have a very high level question that I cant find an answer to that makes sense to me. I understand it''s a terribly broad question but I'm only after some pointers in where to look for answers, not instructions on how to build my site.

So... If I want to render two different types of content in a single page using rails, how would I go about doing this? And how would I format the url? Say I create a gallery model and controller which has information about the gallery and perhaps a description, then I create a gallery-entry controller and model that belongs to the gallery which has an image and image name. If I want to create a url something like `www.siteURL/galleryName/GalleryEntry` that renders both the gallery info and description and all the associated gallery-entries but also a larger version of the gallery-entry that is named in the url where would i start and how would i structure this? How would i go about creating a url that has multiple attributes and how would i access them in the controller/view?

Thanks - and sorry for the vague question

Comment: It looks like you're over thinking this. Load the GalleryEntry in your controller. That should have a `:belongs_to` association to the Gallery, which you can use in your view to display the Gallery info. The Gallery should have a `:has_many` association back to your entries, so you can use that in your view to display the thumbnails of entries related to your main entry.

Comment: this seems to make sense, but what happens is i want to show the gallery with a default image. for example when you fist arrive at the gallery it should show the default image and then when you click the tumbnils you get redirected to the specific image, thanks j

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to go about it.

Your URL looks like a "vanity" URL that would exist in addition a normal RESTful route (`galleries/:gallery_id/entries/:entry_id`). The difference is that you don't want to show *just* the gallery entry.

If you want to specifically differentiate between different views of the same resource there are a number of ways it could be done, the two I'd consider first are adding another action, or adding a disambiguating query parameter. In this case, it's a hybrid, so I'd probably create a custom match and controller method.

The mapping might look like:

```
match ':galleryName/:entryName' => 'gallery#highlight_entry' # Or whatever
```

The action would be (more or less):

```
def highlight_entry
    @gallery = Gallery.find_by_name(...)
    @entries = @gallery.entries
    @highlighted_entry = # pull from @entries, or retrieve
    # Also, filter entries/etc. so the highlighted one doesn't show up
    # etc
end
```